# Is it possible to run script from package.json of angular library (lib1) when run ng build lib1

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, npm-scripts, angular-library

I generated an angular library

```
ng generate library lib1
```

Now I can build generated library with the command:

```
ng build lib1
```

I added tailwind support to this library, so to build tailwind css I need to run cmd:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/lib/tailwind.scss -o ./src/lib/lib1.component.css
```

I added this command to the scripts section of package.json of the library (lib1).

```
"scripts": {
  "build-tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/lib/tailwind.scss -o ./src/lib/lib1.component.css"
}
```

### Question

How to automatically run script `build-tailwind` when run command `ng build lib1`

### Restrictions

- I don't want to use tailwind in a whole app
- I don't want to add global npm script as `"build-lib1": "cd projects/lib1 && npm run build-tailwind && ng build lib1"`